# How do I retrieve only one pair score per trial (in each condition)? (R)

Tags: r

I have done an experiment in which participants have solved a task in pairs with another participant in two different conditions. Each participant has then received a score for how well they did the task individually(score), but the pair has also received a score for how well they did together (pair score). Importantly, the pairs have gone through different amounts of trials, and sometimes one member of a pair is missing in a trial (pls note). However, even if a member is missing in a trial, it can still contribute to the pair score.

I have a data frame similar to the one below:

```
participant <- c(1,2,1,2,3,4,3,4,4,4,6,8)
pair <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3)
condition <- (1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,2,2,1)
trial <- c(1,1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,1)
score <- c(2,3,6,3,4,7,3,1,8,5,4,3)
data <- data.frame(participant, pair, trial, score)

participant pair Condition  trial  score   pair score
    1         1       1        1     2         5
    2         1       1        1     3         5
    1         1       2        2     6         9
    2         1       2        2     3         9
    3         2       1        1     4         11
    4         2       1        1     7         11
    3         2       2        2     3         4
    4         2       2        2     1         4
    4         2       1        3     8         12 (pls note)
    4         2       2        4     5         6  (pls note)
    6         3       2        1     4         8  (pls note)
    8         4       1        1     3         4  (pls note)
```

I would like to do an analysis on pair level in each trial, so I only want one value from each trial from each pair. Does any of you know how I extract only one pair score from each trial?

The dataframe should end up looking something like this:

```
 pair Condition trial  pair score
   1       1       1     5
   1       2       2     9
   2       1       1     11
   2       2       2     4
   2       1       3     12 
   2       2       4     6  
   3       2       1     8 
   4       1       1     4
```

If anyone can help, you will make my day!

Comment: How are the pair scores derived?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for

```
data[!duplicated(data[,c(2,4)]),-c(1,5)]
```

EDIT:

Here is the corrected data that's same as the one printed in the question

```
participant <- c(1,2,1,2,3,4,3,4,4,4,6,8)
pair <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,4)
condition <- c(1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,2,2,1)
trial <- c(1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,3,4,1,1)
score <- c(2,3,6,3,4,7,3,1,8,5,4,3)
pair_score <- c(5, 5, 9, 9, 11, 11, 4, 4, 12, 6, 8, 4)
data <- data.frame(participant, pair, condition, trial, score, "pair score" = pair_score)
```

and running the code on the top gives me the following output:

```
##    pair condition trial pair.score
## 1     1         1     1          5
## 3     1         2     2          9
## 5     2         1     1         11
## 7     2         2     2          4
## 9     2         1     3         12
## 10    2         2     4          6
## 11    3         2     1          8
## 12    4         1     1          4
```

EDIT2:

Forgot to add condition

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Still, the example you showed us is not consistent with the vectors provided, I guess? ... So, once you have the "pair score" calculated, my solution works.

```
participant <- c(1,2,1,2,3,4,3,4,4,4,6,8)
pair <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3)
condition <- c(1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,2,2,1)
trial <- c(1,1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,1)
score <- c(2,3,6,3,4,7,3,1,8,5,4,3)
pair_score <- c(5,5,9,9,11,11,4,4,12,6,8,4)
data <- data.frame(participant, pair, condition, trial, score, "pair.score" = pair_score )

unique_pairscore = unique( pair_score )

data2 <- data.frame("pair"=rep(NA,length(unique_pairscore)),
                    "condition"=rep(NA,length(unique_pairscore)),
                    "trial" = rep(NA,length(unique_pairscore)),
                    "pair.score"=unique_pairscore)

for(i in 1:nrow(data2)){
  data2[i,c("pair","condition","trial")]  <-data[ which(data[,"pair.score"] == data2[i,"pair.score"])[1],c("pair","condition","trial")]
}
```

`data` is:

```
   participant pair condition trial score pair.score
             1    1         1     1     2          5
             2    1         1     1     3          5
             1    1         2     1     6          9
             2    1         2     2     3          9
             3    2         1     1     4         11
             4    2         1     2     7         11
             3    2         2     3     3          4
             4    2         2     1     1          4
             4    2         1     2     8         12
             4    2         2     3     5          6
             6    3         2     1     4          8
             8    3         1     1     3          4
```

`data2` is:

```
  pair condition trial pair.score
     1         1     1          5
     1         2     1          9
     2         1     1         11
     2         2     3          4
     2         1     2         12
     2         2     3          6
     3         2     1          8
```